# Case Then statement for several columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, set, case

How can I set values for two colums, using Case-Then? 
I have next script:

```
  UPDATE [dbo].[operation_data]
SET block_status = CASE
WHEN sd.status = 'X' THEN 'F'
WHEN sd.status != 'X' and od.block_status = 'F' THEN NULL
ELSE block_status
END
FROM operation_data od
JOIN sales_data sd on sd.operation_data_id = od.operation_data_id
GO
```

But I want to do something like this

```
  WHEN sd.status = 'X' THEN 'F' AND main_comment = 'Expired'
```

'main_comment' is column at the operation_data.
As I know CASE can return only single column. Is it some good solution for it?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not statement. (It returns a value.)

Comment: You will have to repeat the CASE expression again for main_content. Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to repeat this for the other column as well:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[operation_data]
SET block_status = CASE
WHEN sd.status = 'X' THEN 'F'
WHEN sd.status != 'X' and od.block_status = 'F' THEN NULL
ELSE block_status
END
, main_comment = CASE
WHEN sd.status = 'X' THEN 'expired'
ELSE main_comment
END
FROM operation_data od
JOIN sales_data sd on sd.operation_data_id = od.operation_data_id
```

Comment: the second CASE should have a `ELSE main_comment` otherwise it will update non matches values with NULL i believe.